# Finding the length of a line through every pixel

Tags: line, distance, arcgis, raster, extract

I have a raster image with multiple polyline feature classes over it. The lines are not overlapping but they are in multiple different orientations. For every pixel in the raster, I want to calculate the length of the line through that pixel so that the result would be a raster with cells assigned a float value of zero to 2^0.5 times the cell size. What's the best way to do this? I'm using ArcPro with an advanced license.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the answers to a similar question here (using R --- but you have a license for that too)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119993/convert-line-shapefile-to-raster-value-total-length-of-lines-within-cell/120175